# Unable to replicate r script to a sql query

Tags: sql, r, count, sum

I am trying to replicate an r script to a SQL query. But, I am unable to achieve the same results. The problem is getting the sum of the date in SQL which is not possible as easy as r script.

R Logic:

The logic used in R is to get the sum of the same dates and it is also filtering by saying the value need not be nan. Also the 1L makes the output column an integer field.

Error in Oracle:

```
SQL Error [30100] [HY000]: Invalid aggregate function 'sum(Enl)': Invalid parameter types of function 'sum(Enl)'
```

R script

```
subjData<- data.frame(
  `Enl` = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05")),
  check.names = F
)
actual.enrollment <- function() {
  if (any(!is.na(subjData$`Enrl`))) {                        
    e0 <- aggregate(1L * !is.na(subjData$`Enl`), by = list(subjData$`Enl`), FUN = sum)
    colnames(e0) <- c("Date", "Enld")
  } else {
    e0 <- data.frame(
      Date = no.dates,
      `Enld` = no.numbers,
      check.names = F
    )
  }
  e0
}

output:

 Date              Enld
1 2020-01-01          2
2 2020-01-03          1
3 2020-01-04          1
4 2020-01-05          1
```

SQL Query tried:

```
SELECT Enl, 
SUM (Enl) as Enld
FROM subjData 
GROUP BY Enl;
```

Comment: It would help your question to also describe the logic here, especially for those who might be experienced with SQL but less so with R.

Comment: Added it, thanks Tim

Comment: I don't know how `NaN` would translate to SQL, but `SUM` already ignores `NULL` values, for whatever this is worth here.

Comment: The sum() column is same as group_by column  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is complaining that you can't sum dates. It looks like you want `count()` instead:

```
select enl, count(*) as enld
from subjdata 
group by enl;
```

I am unclear about what the logic with `null` values should be. If you want to filter out `null` dates, then use a `where` clause:

```
select enl, count(*) as enld
from subjdata 
where enl is not null
group by enl;
```